# How to check Office AddIn Host is running an Outlook application using office.js?

Tags: javascript, office365, office365api, office-2016

Using the Office.js Api how do you determine the current App being used "Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported" only seems to work for Excel & Word, and I would like to check for Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different URLs for the add-in between excel/word and outlook. Or you can check Office.context.mailbox - if it's defined, then you're running in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check with this line of code

```
Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName === "OutlookWebApp"
```